# How to design a User Friendly URI in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, friendly-url

I'm kind of new to CodeIgniter.

I need to design a simple website where I pull out information from a Database. The information from the database is about Ads. I have information about the Country, Country Zone, Zone Location and the kind of the Ad.

My goal is to have an URI like:

```
http://www.someurl.com/index.php/country/country_zone/zone_location/ad_type/title_of_ad
```

There are some information out there on how to do this with CodeIgniter?

Best Regards,

Comment: CI Reactor has support for query strings - you may be better off looking at that, as a URI like that could get confusing pretty fast, whereas `?country=uk&zone=sw&ad_type=full&title=foo` at least has some semantic meaning (perhaps also from an SEO perspective as well as user)

Comment: I think it's going to make sense for you to show what your current URL actually looks like. There are about a million ways to do what you're asking, it's going to depend on what you're working with. I would post your controller as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is with a custom route in your `application/config/routes.php`. Something like this:

```
$route['^(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "your_controller/get_ads/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5";
```

then your controller function would look something like:

```
function get_ads($country, $country_code, $zone_location, $ad_type, $title_of_ad) {
    // your code
}
```

.. you can replace `(:any)` with a more specific regular expression if there is some pattern to the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

the first 2 arguments in your link are your controller name and the method of that controller you want to call.

so

```
http://www.someurl.com/index.php/country/country_zone/zone_location/ad_type/title_of_ad
```

would mean that you call the `country_zone` method of your `country` controller and pass zone_location, add_type and title_of_ad to that method.

what you want ist

```
http://www.someurl.com/index.php/TheControler/themethod/country/country_zone/zone_location/ad_type/title_of_ad
```

implemented like that:

```
class TheControler extends Controler{
    function themethod($country,$country_zone,$zone_location,$ad_type,$title_of_ad){
        //your code
    }
}
```